# Psychometric curve with gradient colours inside PsychShape function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the function PsychShape (inside package MixedPsy) to create the graph of a psychometric curve with given PSE and JND. The function works smoothly and returns a ggplot object that later I can edit to add axis labels, etc. The problem is that I want the curve to have a gradient color going from blue to red, but the command scale_color_gradient seems not to work. R does not return any errors, it seems that it just ignores that instructions.
Can you help me?

My code now looks like this:

```
library(MixedPsy)
PsychShape(pse = MixDelta(model1)[1,1], jnd = MixDelta(model1)[2,1], 
           x.range = c(-2,2), ps.link = c("probit"), ps.size = 2) +
  scale_color_gradient(name = "DT", low = "blue", high = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5,2)) +
  labs(title = "Psychometric Curve", x = "DT = T.target - T.reference [ °C]", y = "Prob. answer 'warmer'") +
  theme(title = element_text(size = 23)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=23)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=21))
```

[image: Result of the code]

Comment: Hey, welcome on StackOverflow! I can not reproduce your plot becaus I do not have your data. Please edit your post to be reproducible, and I am sure you will receive an answer very quickly. By reproducible I mean, try to repeat your issue with some minimal example data. Please post the code used to generate the example data. Alternatively, you can use an inbuilt example data set from R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have your model, but we can create a near identical one.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(MixedPsy)
library(lme4)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(var = seq(-5, 5, len = 100),
                 y = rbinom(100, 1, plogis(seq(-5, 5, len = 100), -0.125, 0.5)),
                 idvar = sample(letters[1:3], 100, TRUE))
             
model1 <- xplode(glmer(cbind(y, 1-y)~var + (1|idvar), data = df,
                       family = binomial(link = "probit")), name.cont = "var")
```

This allows us to recreate your plot using your own plotting code:

```r
p <- PsychShape(pse = MixDelta(model1)[1,1], jnd = MixDelta(model1)[2,1], 
           x.range = c(-2,2), ps.link = c("probit"), ps.size = 2) +
  scale_color_gradient(name = "DT", low = "blue", high = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5,2)) +
  labs(title = "Psychometric Curve", 
       x = "DT = T.target - T.reference [ °C]", y = "Prob. answer 'warmer'") +
  theme(title = element_text(size = 23)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=23)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=21)) 

p
```

[image]

We can reach into the stored ggplot to adjust the aesthetics of the line as follows:

```r
p$layers[[1]]$aes_params <- list(linewidth = 1.5)
p$layers[[1]]$mapping <- aes(x, y, color = y)

p
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: You need to map a variable to the `color` aesthetic if you want to have a gradient. But `color` is already occupied by the `ps.color` argument of the `PsyShape()` function. I copied the `PsyShape()` function source code , removed `ps.color` from it, and saved it as a new function,  `.psyshape2()` - see the end of this answer for result.

---

**Explanation**
If you want to use `scale_color_...()`, something has to be mapped to the `color` aesthetic in the first place, with the `aes(color = variable_name)` function.

Usually, the `aes()`thetic mappings are defined either inside the `ggplot()` function, or in the `geom_...()` function. But `MixedPsy::PsyShape()` is creating those internally, so they are not accessible for easy modification.

But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043913/is-it-possible-to-add-ggplot-aesthetic-without-re-creating-or-modifying-a-geom-l), it is possible to add `aes()`thetic mappings after the fact, just by adding

```r
+ aes(color = variable_name)
```

to your ggplot object. You have to replace `variable_name` with the acual variable name you want to map to color. By looking at the inner workings of `PsyShape()` (put cursor on function name and press F2), I see that they hardcoded `x` and `y` as variable names for `x` and `y` axis. You should be able to just replace `variable_name` with either `x` or `y`, depending on which direction you want the colour gradient.

But this does not work. The reason: `PsyShape()` allows to pass a color with the argument `ps.color` (default = `"black"`). So this means, the color is already set to a fixed value, "black" for example, and trying to call `aes(color = x)` to make a gradient will not override this.

So it is time to just take the original function definition of `PsyShape()` and modify it to our likings. This means, remove the `ps.color` argument, and while we are at it, just create an aesthetic mapping of `x` to `color` inside `geom_line()`.

```r
# Slightly modified function definition of PsyShape()
.psyshape2 <- function(pse = 0, 
                       jnd = 1, 
                       p = 0.75, 
                       x.range = c(NA, NA),
                       ps.link = c("probit"), 
                       ps.type = "solid",
                       ps.size = 1,
                       addTo = NULL) 
{
  if (is.null(addTo)) {
    pl <- ggplot()
  }
  else {
    pl <- addTo
  }
  x = pretty(x.range, 100)
  if (ps.link == "probit") {
    slope = qnorm(p) * (1/jnd)
    y <- pnorm(x, mean = pse, sd = 1/slope)
  }
  else if (ps.link == "logit") {
    slope = log(3) * (1/jnd)
    y = plogis(x, location = pse, scale = 1/slope)
  }
  else {
    warning("The function only works with probit and logit link function")
  }
  data <- data.frame(x, y)
  plot <- list()
  plot$ps <- geom_line(inherit.aes = FALSE,
                       data = data, 
                       # added the color aesthetic
                       aes_string("x", "y", color = "x"),
                       linetype = ps.type, 
                       linewidth = ps.size)
  print(pl + plot)
}
```

**Result** Call the updated function and customize the gradient colors:

```r
.psyshape2(pse = 0, jnd = 6, x.range = c(-40, 40), ps.size = 3) +
  scale_color_gradient(name = "DT", low = "blue", high = "red") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Good answer with a creative approach and explanation @uke, upvoted. But you don't need to hack the function to change the aesthetics - you can modify the plot post-hoc.

Comment: Thanks, and I think you are right. Modifying aesthetic params after the fact in the innards of the ggplot object, like your answer is showing, is more concise. Good to know that you can just override it like that. I did not try because I thought I do not know enough about the inner structure of the ggplot object - it looks just like a scary long nested list, but in the end it seems to be pretty straight forward and not that complicated.

Comment: it's long and complicated, but not scary. ggplot is very modular, so there are some patterns you can find in the structure. It's good to have a poke around at the innards and see what you can do. Maybe even have a go at creating a new geom for practice if you enjoy tinkering.

Comment: Thank you anyway for all the effort put into providing me with a reply. I learned a lot from it :)